# How can I capture PhantomJS errors in java object via selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I want to capture all the js errors in the result.
I am injecting js file in a html via phantomjs and saving the output. But want to capture all js errors in result after execution.

**Below is my code:**

```
PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

String script = <...Some script...page.injectJs('example.js').....>;
Object result = driver.executePhantomJS(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

String CatchS = (String) js.executeScript(yourJSScript);

executeScript returns one of Boolean, Long, String, List or WebElement. Or null.